# what event fires when activating a customer in magento

Tags: magento, events

I have written a Magento module to do something when a customer is activated (admin must approve / activate all new customer registrations).

In my config.xml I have used `adminhtml_customer_save_after` as the code of the event to fire my function.

This works fine if I actually go into the customer record, make a change and save it. However if I simply select 'customer activated' from the Actions drop down in the main Customers > Manage Customers page and submit it does not fire.

Is there a different event code I can use to trigger my function in this case?
I've looked through this great resource [link]http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7 but can't see any other likely suspects.

Many thanks

Thanks for looking Keyur, 
this is the code of my app/code/local/customcron/updateaddress/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<modules>

    <CustomCron_UpdateAddress>

        <version>0.0.1</version>

    </CustomCron_UpdateAddress>

</modules>

<global>

    <models>

        <customcron_updateaddress>

            <class>CustomCron_UpdateAddress_Model</class>

        </customcron_updateaddress>

    </models>

    <events>

        <customer_save_before>

            <observers>

                <customcron_updateaddress>

                    <class>customcron_updateaddress/observer</class>

                    <method>addrUpdate</method>

                    <type>singleton</type>

                </customcron_updateaddress>

            </observers>

        </customer_save_before>

    </events>

</global>
```

and this is the code of my app/code/local/customcron/updateaddress/model/observer.php

```
class CustomCron_UpdateAddress_Model_Observer
{
public function addrUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
        // Retrieve the Customer being updated from the event observer
    if($observer->getCustomer()) {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        //$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

            // Get the details from customer object
        $customer_id = $customer->getId();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        Mage::log(
            "{$customer_id} {$name} ({$email}) updated",
            null, 
            'customer-updates.log'
        );
```

etc.
This goes on to check if there is already an address stored and if not  get the details and update the relevant tables to add an address.
However so far this only fires when the record is opened and saved (not even on 'save and continue edit') and only if I use adminhtml_customer_save_after. If I use anything other than that either it does not fire at all or I get a '$customer is not an object' error.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change in any record of customer  `customerSaveBefore` event always fire even in your case when you change customer attribute from manage customer or if you actually go into the customer record, make a change and save it.

```
customerSaveBefore event always execute before any changes on customer
```

Comment: Hi Keyur, using `<customer_save_before>` does not appear to fire when activating directly from Customers > Manage Customers page. I recorded a list of events, I didn't see `customer_save_before` but did get `controller_action_predispatch_customeractivation` and `controller_action_postdispatch_customeractivation`. However if I use these I don't appear to be able to query it in my module - `$customer = $observer->getCustomer();` returns a non object. Do I have to query these in a different way or is there some other event I can listen out for? Thank you for any insight.

Comment: customer_save_before always execute when any changes on customer and it works for me with your conditiin...have you try this solution?

Comment: Hi Keyur, thanks for your help, I updated my question above to include my code, could something else be incorrect that is preventing or altering the normal, expected behaviour on customer_save_before?